# SDL_Texture from IMG_Load() fails to draw?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl-2, sdl-image

The only thing I see is the RenderDrawColor.

Also the "circle.png" is in the right folder (where the main.cpp is).

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_Image.h>

int main(int argc,char* args[]) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("_", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer* render = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(render,0, 255, 255, 255);
    SDL_Surface* img = IMG_Load("circle.png");
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(render, img);
    SDL_FreeSurface(img);

    SDL_Event event;
    while (1) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                return 0;
            }
        }
    SDL_RenderClear(render);
    SDL_RenderCopy(render, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(render);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you've verified (with a debugger/`printf()`/etc.) that `img` & `texture` are non-NULL?

Comment: `int img_flag = IMG_INIT_PNG;
  if (!(IMG_Init(img_flag) & img_flag)) {
   std::cout << "error";
  };` Outputs an error.

Answer (score 1):

Had to include zlib1.dll and libpng16-16.dll to the same folder as the cpp.

libpng16-16.dll depends on zlib1.dll.